# Can We Protect Against XSRF With Session Cookie Authentication?

Tags: http, httpsession

We have taken over a legacy app and want to start writing Single Page Application components for it.

We understand the two most common attack vectors are XSS and CSRF.

Given this app uses Session Cookie style authentication we will turn on HTTPOnly cookies on the session cookie (to protect it against XSS).

However I am a little confused about dealing with CSRF attacks.

Currently the app will produce a hidden 'token' on every form POST request which is double checked with session when the request comes back in to the server.

However we have hundreds of JSON Ajax calls happening now and the single form posts are now irrelevant.

We would like to generate a CSRF token and simply keep passing it in the header with each AJAX request. But will this actually work?

If we just generate a XSRF token at login and then simply keep passing it back up the wire on each request (in the header) can we expect this be classed as secure?

Comment: Is there a distinction between XSRF and CSRF here?

Comment: "_we will turn on HTTPOnly cookies on the session cookie (to protect it against XSS)_" What exact protection do you expect from XSS?